# Building a "Portal Application Archive" *.PAA using Maven

Tags: java, maven, websphere-portal

We are looking to build multiple *.PAA files to deploy on IBM websphere 8.5.

I would love to use maven to consolidate our existing Portal *.war projects into a PAA file.

A PAA file is just like an EAR file - but with more structure in it.
see here for specs: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.0.0/config/si_paa_spec.dita

Is this do-able ?   or should I just use antscript ?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Definately do-able.  We have implemented a solution to do exactly this but for Portal 8.0.0.1, the solution has been used for managing 40+ war files, themes, jars, and other artifacts supported by the PAA.

These are the steps involved in creating our solution:

1. Create a new PAA manually without the WAR files (i.e. copy provided sample PAA, rename folders and property file, and edit sdd.xml files).  Make sure to test this manual PAA by placing a test WAR file in it and make sure that it gets deployed.
2. Create a new simple maven pom project
3. Copy the PAA project (without WAR files) into src/main/resources (you could either add this as a resources directory or use the maven-resources-plugin to add them to the target dir)
4. Add all your WAR files and other artifacts as dependencies in your pom.xml files (we used **classifiers** to distinguished between normal WAR files and Portlet WAR files, but that does require the source projects to specify the classifier in their pom)
5. Use the maven-assembly-plugin's **dependencySet** feature to copy your dependencies in the specific location needed by the PAA.  Use the **fileSet** feature to include the project PAA files copied earlier.  Make sure that the assembly package.xml generates a zip file and does not include the base directory.

Sample dependencySet in package.xml (Note usage of classifier *webapp* for standalone WAR files)

> ```
>     <dependencySet>
>         <unpack>false</unpack>
>         <scope>runtime</scope>
>         <outputDirectory>myApp/components/MyApp/installableApps/war</outputDirectory>
>         <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
>         <includes>
>             <include>*:war:webapp</include>
>         </includes>
>     </dependencySet>
>     <dependencySet>
>         <unpack>false</unpack>
>         <scope>runtime</scope>
>         <outputDirectory>myApp/components/MyApp/installableApps/portlets</outputDirectory>
>         <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
>         <includes>
>             <include>*:war</include>
>         </includes>
>     </dependencySet>
> ```

Comment: How would one package a paa as a zip but end up with a .paa file?